# Highstock Single Line Series Data format

Tags: python, mysql, django, highcharts

I want to use Highstock  Single Line series chart but there is no documentation about the data format. The data given there is in this format:

```
/* Jul 2008 */
[1215388800000,25.02],
[1215475200000,25.65],
[1215561600000,24.89],
[1215648000000,25.23],
[1215734400000,24.65],
[1215993600000,24.84],
[1216080000000,24.23],
[1216166400000,24.69],
[1216252800000,24.54],
[1216339200000,23.59],
[1216598400000,23.76],
[1216684800000,23.15],
[1216771200000,23.75],
[1216857600000,22.72],
[1216944000000,23.16],
[1217203200000,22.06],
[1217289600000,22.44],
[1217376000000,22.84],
[1217462400000,22.71],
```

I am using Django. How do I convert the timestamp fetched fro MySQL 'TIMESTAMP' datatype to this format?

Comment: What field type is it? There's no such thing as 'TIMESTAMP' in django.

Comment: I am getting the data from a MySQL table whose fieldtype is Timestamp

Comment: By using raw SQL? That's not the right way to do things in django.

Comment: It's a very complex query. ORM wasn't cutting it.

Comment: Is this format called epoch seconds? The one that HS uses?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working. I put in the UNIX time and this is what I get:http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/basic-line/

Comment: I don't see what doesn't work with that, and yes, those are unix epochs.

Comment: [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#series<line>.data) docs about required format. So, well, **there is** documentation for data format ;)